# ¿Como inserto un UserControl con binding en un formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, binding, usercontrol

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de insertar un UserControl en un formulario. Arrastro mi UserControl al formulario, guardo y me sale la siguiente pantalla:

[image: Error del designer cuando quiere renderizar]

Busque por SO y hay alguien que tuvo el mismo problema que yo pero no logro entender la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997368/binding-error-in-design-and-runtime-on-usercontrol) o que decir con ella.

Les muestro brevemente el código y algunas indicaciones para que puedan orientarme en el asunto.

Este es el UserControl y como esta bindeado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase que esta bindeada a **bsControl** es la siguiente:

```
namespace SmartInventorySystem.ViewModel.Controls
{
    public class DispenseCartControlViewModel : FormViewModel
    {
        public DispenseCartControlViewModel()
        {
            ItemsToCheckout = new List<ItemToCheckoutRowViewModel>();
        }

        public List<ItemToCheckoutRowViewModel> ItemsToCheckout { get; set; }

        public decimal SubTotal
        {
            get; //=> ItemsToCheckout.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.UnitPrice);
            set;
        }

        public decimal Discount { get; set; }
        public decimal Vat { get; set; }
        public decimal Total
        {
            get; //=> SubTotal - Discount + Vat > 0 ? (Vat / 100 * (SubTotal - Discount)) : 0;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo, el codigo que tiene el control:

```
public partial class DispenseCartControl : UserControl, IDispenseCartView
    {
        private readonly DispenseCartPresenter _presenter;

        public DispenseCartControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _presenter = new DispenseCartPresenter(this);

            State = new DispenseCartControlViewModel();
        }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public DispenseCartControlViewModel State { get; set; }

        public void ShowError(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Dispense Cart", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        public void ShowInfo(string msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, msg, "Dispense Cart", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        public void UpdateFormBindingSource()
        {
            bsControl.ResetBindings(false);
        }

        private void DispenseCartControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bsControl.DataSource = State;
        }
    }
```

**Actualización 1**: Agrego el call-stack de donde me lanza error el designer.

> at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.SetBindingManagerBase(BindingManagerBase lManager)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetListManager(BindingManagerBase bindingManagerBase)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ListManagerBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.UpdateBinding(BindingContext newBindingContext, Binding binding)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_BindingContextInternal(BindingContext value)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.set_BindingContext(BindingContext value)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.get_BindingContext()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContextInternal()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.get_BindingContext()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContextInternal()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContext()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContextInternal()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.get_BindingContext()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContextInternal()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.get_BindingContext()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.OnCreateControl()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.DesignerControlCollection.Add(Control c)

Comment: Lo que dice el error, es que el diseñador te esta seteando una de todas esas propiedades publicas a null (deberia ser el binding), y por eso da el error. Lo que hizo el otro usuario fue chequear que no fuera null antes de tratar de usarla. Tene en cuenta que el diseñador usa algunos de esos metodos en el diseño.

Comment: Pero todas las propiedades del ViewModel son ValueType... son estructuras. No son ReferenceType. Si me lo decis por la lista, debería estar inicializada por el ctor.

Comment: y por ejemplo la lista no trata de conectarse a una db? eso no va a ocurrir en tiempo de diseño.. pero el constructor si se va a ejecutar :)

Comment: El UserControl esta _pelado_ literalmente; carece de lógica. Además comente las líneas donde se usa Linq para hacer agregación para evitar problemas por temas de inicialización. Desconozco como instancia el diseñador el UserControl. Para mi, ese territorio, es místico hasta cierto punto.

Comment: hace una cosa.. mira el call stack y fijate en que linea falla...

Comment: @gbianchi ahi agregue el call-stack... no dice mucho.

Comment: Cierto.. a ver si alguien viendolo se le ocurre algo..

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97652/discussion-between-drielnox-and-gbianchi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A veces, la solución correcta, es la más simple y menos obvia que pueda parecer.

Me cito, a mismo, para contar esta experiencia.

Investigando un poco mas, encontre un articulo fabuloso para aquellas personas que tengan problemas con los errores en tiempo de diseño: [Walkthrough: Debugging Custom Windows Forms Controls at Design Time](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-debugging-custom-windows-forms-controls-at-design-time)

Comencé debugeando el designer de VS, según la guía, y noto que no hay ningún problema en la inicialización del control, ni en lo binding. Frustrado, pruebo varias variantes pero nada.

Entonces, cerré todo... Mágicamente, cuando abro nuevamente el VS y la solución, el control es mostrado en el designer sin ningun problema.

**Moraleja:** Las soluciones del tipo "*Apague y vuelva a encender*", soluciona muchos problemas. Mas que nada por que esta solución habla sobre (la re-inicialización de) los estados(de las variables y cache) de la aplicacion.

Cada que vez que se aplica esta solución, se reinicializa todos los estados y la caché está limpia. En este caso, fue del VS. Especulo que fue que, en cache del designer, tenia una version vieja del control y/o del formulario donde estaba el control.